# How to find the device details for android

Tags: android

I want to find out about the name, android version, screen size, battery status, network status and other details of the device on which the app is running. Is there a specific inbuilt class for the device details or will I have to use some third party tool.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html  and http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For getting Manufacturer,model and version use,

**

```
Build.MANUFACTURER
Build.MODEL;
Build.VERSION.RELEASE
```

**

For Screen Size use,

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        width = display.getWidth();  //deprecated
        height = display.getHeight();//deprecated
```

Comment: Just want to point out that the way you're getting the Screen Size is now deprecated =/.

Comment: DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;

Answer (score 0):

```
    TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
     Log.i("model", android.os.Build.MODEL);
 WindowManager mWinMgr = (WindowManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        _sWidth= mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        _sHeight = mWinMgr.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no single class or utility you can use to get all of that. You can however, visit these links for information on how to get each one of them:

[Battery Level](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-battery-level-in-android-using.html)

[Android Version](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html)

[Screen Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

[Network Status](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2011/01/to-check-internet-connection-statustype.html)

I just googled each of them really. Good news is, you have google on your machine too!